# Why is it "bad" to use cin for numeric variables?

Tags: c++, cin

My current professor states on his syllabus:

"Never use cin >> to read directly into a numeric variable, like int or double or float. Read as a string (C or C++) and convert to a number using atoi or atof."

Is there a reason for this? At first I thought it is to avoid fail flags but if you just add input validation code isn't it fine to "cin >> myInt"?

Using his method, if they entered "4a5" and I did atoi wouldn't it still throw an error?

Thanks~

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing wrong with doing that. Although you can run into fun problems if you 450euros (and you try to read 450 as float) [as with this user](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27945250/583833)

Comment: It probably is for input validation.  Strings are delimited by whitespace in your example, while numeric types have more surprising rules and edge cases.

Comment: `My current professor states on his syllabus [...] Is there a reason for this?` In addition to any answers here, it'd be good to get your professor's input, since he's the one that put it there. `wouldn't it still throw an error?` You could try it yourself!

Comment: "convert to a number using atoi or atof" is terrible advice, since you should always prefer `strtol` and `strtod`.

Comment: First of all, [`atoi`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) scans the initial portion of the string, so the result in your example would be `4`. In addition, there's no way to detect errors using `atoi`, which is why you should use [`strtol`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) instead.

Comment: I would suspect that the professor has this so that the students are not mixing their input operations.  It is well known mixing `>>` with `getline()` can cause issues with the input buffer.  If you only ever use `getline()` you never have to deal with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, there is nothing wrong with it at all. This advice would seem to be wrong.

In fact, by relying solely on `stoi` and friends, you lose *any* ability to control the conversion process. You might want to use these in some very domain-specific cases where you want to extract a specific number of characters and *then* attempt to convert them, but that's down to business logic.

Certainly, relying on antiquated code like `atoi` is even worse, what with its *undefined behaviour* on encountering many failure cases.

Comment: You should actually mention how to cleanup stream state, after reading had failed, because of parsing failures.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Nah I'm not here to teach the feature

Comment: Hmm, C99 actually does use the phrase "behavior is undefined".  So it is the cppreference.com documentation site that is in error.

Answer (score 1):

It is not bad, but it is unsafe: if the stream gets invalid data it will end up in a "fail" state. This means the programmer needs to check if the stream is still working, then process the data. If not, everything after the fail is lost when resetting the stream.

Getline is better for these situations because it doesn't work the same way, it will just accept all input as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is valid code...

```
int num;
cin >> num;
```

... problems will arise if the user inputs a character that can't be interpreted as an int.

That's why it's safer to use string variables with cin and do the data extraction programmatically.

Comment: Can you detail one of these "problems" and explain why `std::atoi` is better at resolving them?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Can you detail what control over conversion you have with `cin` that you don't have with `strtol` or `stoi`?  (Note that I count facets as an extra step that must be performed on iostreams, since the initial configuration is unknown, while `strtol` and `stoi` are in a useful configuration immediately)

Comment: @BenVoigt: All of the I/O manipulators.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: These functions allow you to specify decimal, octal, binary, or hexadecimal just fine, or auto-detection (third argument).  That's *more* powerful than `operator>>`

Comment: @BenVoigt: How do you auto-detect that a string `59` should be parsed as hex?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That should *not* be parsed as hex *automatically*, because it doesn't start with `0x`.  If you want to force hex input, you will not use automatic base, but make the third parameter 16.  That's more powerful than `operator>>`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: No, of course it should not be parsed as hex automatically. I know that (as you are well aware). It was my point. As for the base parameter.. dammit (though that still does not make it "more powerful")

Comment: (Its ability to specify near-arbitrary bases is :P)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That's why I mentioned binary, which the iostream `operator>>` can't do.  Recognition of base prefixes is also a feature unmatched by `operator>>`

Comment: @BenVoigt: Still doesn't seem like a good reason to blanketly adopt it. Extracting a string first before being a converter into it is logically more difficult and requires more computation.